# get current database sysdate using java instead of sql

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sysdate

it is possible to get the current system date of oracle database using this query,

```
SELECT sysdate FROM dual;

select (sysdate - to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) * 86400 unix_ts from dual;
```

which returns 19-DEC-12 and 1355949236.999999999999999999999999999998 format respectively.

**what if i need it to get it from *java* perspective and in unix_time format?**

1) what is the library name?

e.g.:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import com.portal.pcm.fields.TmFldRefundIndLastModDate;
```

2) how to call it?

e.g.:

```
if(sysdate >= a_date_which_is_in_unix_time_format){...}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
long seconds = new java.util.Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

See the docs for [Date#getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)

Comment: Thanks msandiford. /1000 to change it back to sec which will get the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (unix time) =).